# Comparing two db tables and appending values from one to another

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I have two DB tables. The first, `all_data`, contains around 4m rows with information on user interactions on a site. The second, `region`, contains a list of 1,800 towns in the UK, with their corresponding `county` and `TV region`.

One of the `all_data` columns references the town where the user lives.
I need to check each row of `all_data` against all the rows of `region`. If the town matches, I need to append the `county` and `TV region` from `region` to the row in `all_data`.

I’m relatively new to `SQL` and I’m having trouble visualizing how this should work. As this is taking place in `BigQuery`, I need to keep processing costs to a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a `left join`:

```
select a.*, r.country, r.tv_region
from all_data a left join
     region r
     on a.town = r.town;
```

Comment: @lightfoot34 . . . I would caution you that in the US there are (many) examples of different towns having the same name.  I think it is said that all states have a "Springfield", for example.

Comment: Very good point - thanks for that. I can mitigate this somewhat here by including the region (England, NI, Wales, Scotland).